# JavaScript alert under Update Panel

Tags: javascript, asp.net-ajax, alert

I am using an Ajax tab container, and each tab panel containing an user control.

I am also using an update panel.

Everything is working fine.

But, when I am trying to raise a javascript alert, it is blanking the portion of screen that is inside the update panel. When clicked on OK of alert, it is rendering properly.

I was unable to trace out what is the exact problem. Is it because of the Update Panel?

What are the other ways we can raise an alert message instead of using javascript?

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: Without some code, I guess nobody really can help you... Unless you want somebody to guess what's the problem is.

Comment: ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.upEdit, typeof(string), "message2", "alert('xyz)", true); this is the code used for raising alert

Comment: Post the ENTIRE code...maybe you can use [this site](http://jsfiddle). A couple of instructions aren't enough to undertand all

Comment: Sorry that , i can not expose code because of confidentiality. But i can explain the scenario. I have an ajax tab container inside which i am embedding five user controls in each of tab panel . Here, i am loading data to each user control on the ActiveTabChanged Server Event of Tab Container. So, for that i am using Update Panel to stop entire post back and perform partial post back. When i am raising java script alert from the page which is under this panel , the alert is coming but it is blanking the screen behind

Comment: Sorry but it's like if you go to the doctor and tell him "I've shoulder pain when I move it in this way but I can't show you because I'm shy". Try to reproduce the error in another situation that you can show us and add the code in the question.

Comment: I understand..i will mock the code

Comment: Are you using Mozila Firefox :D ?

Comment: No..Internet explorer 6